Covariance from a Joint Probability Function
I have a question from a textbook, which I think is wrong.
The question gives a joint probability function:



X/Y
0
2
3




0
0.1
0.1
0


3
0.25
0.2
0.15


6
0.16
0
0.04



and they ask what is the covariance.
The answer is 2.91.
I believe it is wrong.
According to my calculations:
$E(XY)=3.27$ and $E(X)=3$ and $E(Y)=1.17$, so $COV(X,Y)=-0.24$
Where is the mistake ?

Could you please show all your calculations?  How specifically do you get from $E[XY],E[X],$ and $E[Y]$ to the final result?

what's wrong with my arithmetic ? E(XY)=000.1+020.1+030+300.25+320.2+330.15+600.16+620+630.04

E(X)=3*(0.25+0.2+0.15) + 6*(0.16+0.04)

E(Y)=2*(0.1+0.2) + 3*(0.15+0.04)

The arithmetic is fine.  Now that you have checked it, is there anything left to answer?

Yeah, why does textbooks makes mistakes ? :-) It's very confusing.

All textbooks contain errors because people are imperfect.  An important part of learning how to learn is to exploit this fact: seek out mistakes and appreciate them for what they are, which is additional opportunities to test your understanding.  That's an essential step towards becoming an expert yourself--which (among other things) means that you don't have some other authority (like the text or a teacher) to rely on.

Did you check the errata for the textbook? A lot of newer books will have documentation for known issues and a method for reporting when you find one that isn't listed.

I don't recall having read a textbook without any errors. Good ones (among a number of other important attributes) would tend to have few errors, mostly inconsequential.

As a rule, even the best textbooks (and most research papers) contain small errors.  It is useful to learn how to check such authorities yourself.
In statistics (and often in mathematics), drawing pictures often helps.  Here, for example, is a plot of this distribution displaying the probabilities with colors (lighter is higher) and point areas:

The slanted line is the linear regression of $y$ against $x.$  Thus, its slope is proportional to the covariance.
Which answer is this line consistent with, $2.91$ or $-0.24$?

Use mathematica to verify the calculation.
(*Define the joint probability distribution*)
jointProb = {{0.1, 0.1, 0}, {0.25, 0.2, 0.15}, {0.16, 0, 0.04}};

(*Define the values of X and Y*)
xValues = {0, 3, 6};
yValues = {0, 2, 3};

(*Compute E[X],E[Y],and E[XY]*)

(*Expected value of X*)
pX = Total[jointProb, {2}]; (*Marginal probabilities for X*)
EX = Total[xValues*pX];

(*Expected value of Y*)
pY = Total[jointProb]; (*Marginal probabilities for Y*)
EY = Total[yValues*pY];

(*Expected value of XY*)
EXY = Total[
   Flatten[Table[
     xValues[[i]]*yValues[[j]]*jointProb[[i, j]], {i, 1, 
      Length[xValues]}, {j, 1, Length[yValues]}]]];

(*Covariance*)
covXY = EXY - EX*EY;
covXY

-0.24

Below is a plot of this distribution displaying the probabilities with colors.
(*Define the joint probability distribution*)
jointProb = {{0.1, 0.1, 0}, {0.25, 0.2, 0.15}, {0.16, 0, 0.04}};

(*Define the values of X and Y*)
xValues = {0, 3, 6};
yValues = {0, 2, 3};

(*Create the data points and corresponding weights*)
dataPoints = 
  Flatten[Table[{xValues[[i]], yValues[[j]]}, {i, 1, 
     Length[xValues]}, {j, 1, Length[yValues]}], 1];
weights = Flatten[jointProb];

(*Filter out the points where the probability is zero*)
filteredData = 
  Select[Transpose[{dataPoints, weights}], #[[2]] > 0 &];
dataPointsFiltered = filteredData[[All, 1]];
weightsFiltered = filteredData[[All, 2]];

(*Perform weighted linear regression*)
lm = LinearModelFit[dataPointsFiltered, x, x, 
   Weights -> weightsFiltered];

(*Define a function to map probabilities to colors*)
colorFunction[p_] := 
  ColorData["TemperatureMap"][
   Rescale[p, {Min[weightsFiltered], Max[weightsFiltered]}]];

(*Plot the data points with color based on probability*)
coloredPoints = 
  MapThread[{PointSize[Large], 
     Style[Point[#1], colorFunction[#2]]} &, {dataPointsFiltered, 
    weightsFiltered}];

(*Create a horizontal color bar legend with smaller size*)
colorBar = 
  BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {Min[weightsFiltered], 
     Max[weightsFiltered]}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
   LegendLabel -> "Probability", 
   LegendLayout -> "Row",(*Horizontal layout*)
   "LegendMarkerSize" -> {180, 
     10} (*Adjust the width and height of the color bar*)];

(*Plot the regression line*)
regressionLine = 
  Plot[lm[x], {x, Min[xValues], Max[xValues]}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Regression Line"}];

(*Display the points with color,regression line,and horizontal color \
bar below*)
GraphicsGrid[{{Show[Graphics[coloredPoints], regressionLine, 
    Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, 
    PlotRange -> {{Min[xValues], Max[xValues]}, {Min[yValues], 
       Max[yValues]}}]}, {colorBar} (*Place the horizontal color bar \
below*)}]


